# c# deployment : application failed to start

Tags: c#, deployment

I deployed my C# application using the **InstallShield 2012** 
But when i launch the application it stops and gives the following **error**

```
    Problem signature:

      Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3

      Problem Signature 01: marshal laboratories.exe

      Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0

      Problem Signature 03: 53f8289d

      Problem Signature 04: Marshal Laboratories

      Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0

      Problem Signature 06: 53f8289d

      Problem Signature 07: de5

      Problem Signature 08: e

      Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileLoadException

      OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1

      Locale ID:    1033

      Additional Information 1: 0a9e
      Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
      Additional Information 3: 0a9e
      Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: Is the corect .net framework installed on that deployment box? Is it an 64 bits exe where the OS is only 32bits? If you run [procesmonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) which file couldn't be found? You coud also try the Assembly Binding Log Viewer to see if you miss an assemlby.

Comment: Make sure that all the referenced assemblies  of your project/solution are deployed on the client pc